# Ubuntu 14.04 Lts not detecting bluetooth devices in Lenovo E440

Tags: 14.04, bluetooth, lenovo

My lenovo e440 machine using ubuntu14.04 lts wansn't able to detect any bluetooth devices, i tried to install blueman but didn't help...could someone be so nice as to help :)

code:

```
lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net
04:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 10)
Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:5028]
Kernel driver in use: r8169
05:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]
Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:b728]
Kernel driver in use: rtl8723be
wuzongcai@WuZongCai-Machine:~$ lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net
04:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 10)
Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:5028]
Kernel driver in use: r8169
05:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]
Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:b728]
Kernel driver in use: rtl8723be
```

code:

```
lsusb

Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0bda:b728 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 5986:0397 Acer, Inc 
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 138a:0011 Validity Sensors, Inc. VFS5011 Fingerprint Reader
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

code:

```
sudo cat /sys/kernel/debug/usb/devices
T:  Bus=04 Lev=00 Prnt=00 Port=00 Cnt=00 Dev#=  1 Spd=5000 MxCh= 6
B:  Alloc=  0/800 us ( 0%), #Int=  0, #Iso=  0
D:  Ver= 3.00 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=03 MxPS= 9 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=1d6b ProdID=0003 Rev= 3.16
S:  Manufacturer=Linux 3.16.0-49-generic xhci_hcd
S:  Product=xHCI Host Controller
S:  SerialNumber=0000:00:14.0
C:* #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=  0mA
I:* If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub
E:  Ad=81(I) Atr=03(Int.) MxPS=   4 Ivl=256ms

T:  Bus=03 Lev=00 Prnt=00 Port=00 Cnt=00 Dev#=  1 Spd=480  MxCh=14
B:  Alloc=  0/800 us ( 0%), #Int=  0, #Iso=  0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=1d6b ProdID=0002 Rev= 3.16
S:  Manufacturer=Linux 3.16.0-49-generic xhci_hcd
S:  Product=xHCI Host Controller
S:  SerialNumber=0000:00:14.0
C:* #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=  0mA
I:* If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub
E:  Ad=81(I) Atr=03(Int.) MxPS=   4 Ivl=256ms

T:  Bus=03 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=06 Cnt=01 Dev#=  2 Spd=12   MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.10 Cls=e0(wlcon) Sub=01 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=0bda ProdID=b728 Rev= 2.00
S:  Manufacturer=Realtek 
S:  Product=Bluetooth Radio 
S:  SerialNumber=00e04c000001
C:* #Ifs= 2 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=500mA
I:* If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 3 Cls=e0(wlcon) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=btusb
E:  Ad=81(I) Atr=03(Int.) MxPS=  16 Ivl=1ms
E:  Ad=02(O) Atr=02(Bulk) MxPS=  64 Ivl=0ms
E:  Ad=82(I) Atr=02(Bulk) MxPS=  64 Ivl=0ms
I:* If#= 1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=e0(wlcon) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=btusb
E:  Ad=03(O) Atr=01(Isoc) MxPS=   0 Ivl=1ms
E:  Ad=83(I) Atr=01(Isoc) MxPS=   0 Ivl=1ms
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 1 #EPs= 2 Cls=e0(wlcon) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=btusb
E:  Ad=03(O) Atr=01(Isoc) MxPS=   9 Ivl=1ms
E:  Ad=83(I) Atr=01(Isoc) MxPS=   9 Ivl=1ms
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 2 #EPs= 2 Cls=e0(wlcon) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=btusb
E:  Ad=03(O) Atr=01(Isoc) MxPS=  17 Ivl=1ms
E:  Ad=83(I) Atr=01(Isoc) MxPS=  17 Ivl=1ms
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 3 #EPs= 2 Cls=e0(wlcon) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=btusb
E:  Ad=03(O) Atr=01(Isoc) MxPS=  25 Ivl=1ms
E:  Ad=83(I) Atr=01(Isoc) MxPS=  25 Ivl=1ms
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 4 #EPs= 2 Cls=e0(wlcon) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=btusb
E:  Ad=03(O) Atr=01(Isoc) MxPS=  33 Ivl=1ms
E:  Ad=83(I) Atr=01(Isoc) MxPS=  33 Ivl=1ms
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 5 #EPs= 2 Cls=e0(wlcon) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=btusb
E:  Ad=03(O) Atr=01(Isoc) MxPS=  49 Ivl=1ms
E:  Ad=83(I) Atr=01(Isoc) MxPS=  49 Ivl=1ms

T:  Bus=03 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=10 Cnt=02 Dev#=  3 Spd=12   MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 1.10 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=11 Prot=ff MxPS= 8 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=138a ProdID=0011 Rev= 0.78
S:  SerialNumber=4488af17af9c
C:* #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=a0 MxPwr=100mA
I:* If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 4 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=(none)
E:  Ad=01(O) Atr=02(Bulk) MxPS=  64 Ivl=0ms
E:  Ad=81(I) Atr=02(Bulk) MxPS=  64 Ivl=0ms
E:  Ad=82(I) Atr=02(Bulk) MxPS=  64 Ivl=0ms
E:  Ad=83(I) Atr=03(Int.) MxPS=   8 Ivl=4ms

T:  Bus=03 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=11 Cnt=03 Dev#=  4 Spd=480  MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=ef(misc ) Sub=02 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=5986 ProdID=0397 Rev=14.80
S:  Manufacturer=Vimicro corp.
S:  Product=Integrated Camera
C:* #Ifs= 2 Cfg#= 1 Atr=80 MxPwr=256mA
A:  FirstIf#= 0 IfCount= 2 Cls=0e(video) Sub=03 Prot=00
I:* If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=0e(video) Sub=01 Prot=00 Driver=uvcvideo
E:  Ad=81(I) Atr=03(Int.) MxPS=  16 Ivl=2ms
I:* If#= 1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 0 Cls=0e(video) Sub=02 Prot=00 Driver=uvcvideo
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 1 #EPs= 1 Cls=0e(video) Sub=02 Prot=00 Driver=uvcvideo
E:  Ad=82(I) Atr=05(Isoc) MxPS= 128 Ivl=125us
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 2 #EPs= 1 Cls=0e(video) Sub=02 Prot=00 Driver=uvcvideo
E:  Ad=82(I) Atr=05(Isoc) MxPS= 512 Ivl=125us
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 3 #EPs= 1 Cls=0e(video) Sub=02 Prot=00 Driver=uvcvideo
E:  Ad=82(I) Atr=05(Isoc) MxPS=1024 Ivl=125us
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 4 #EPs= 1 Cls=0e(video) Sub=02 Prot=00 Driver=uvcvideo
E:  Ad=82(I) Atr=05(Isoc) MxPS=1536 Ivl=125us
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 5 #EPs= 1 Cls=0e(video) Sub=02 Prot=00 Driver=uvcvideo
E:  Ad=82(I) Atr=05(Isoc) MxPS=2048 Ivl=125us
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 6 #EPs= 1 Cls=0e(video) Sub=02 Prot=00 Driver=uvcvideo
E:  Ad=82(I) Atr=05(Isoc) MxPS=2688 Ivl=125us
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 7 #EPs= 1 Cls=0e(video) Sub=02 Prot=00 Driver=uvcvideo
E:  Ad=82(I) Atr=05(Isoc) MxPS=3072 Ivl=125us

T:  Bus=02 Lev=00 Prnt=00 Port=00 Cnt=00 Dev#=  1 Spd=480  MxCh= 3
B:  Alloc=  0/800 us ( 0%), #Int=  0, #Iso=  0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=1d6b ProdID=0002 Rev= 3.16
S:  Manufacturer=Linux 3.16.0-49-generic ehci_hcd
S:  Product=EHCI Host Controller
S:  SerialNumber=0000:00:1d.0
C:* #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=  0mA
I:* If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub
E:  Ad=81(I) Atr=03(Int.) MxPS=   4 Ivl=256ms

T:  Bus=02 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=00 Cnt=01 Dev#=  2 Spd=480  MxCh= 8
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=8087 ProdID=8000 Rev= 0.04
C:* #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=  0mA
I:* If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub
E:  Ad=81(I) Atr=03(Int.) MxPS=   2 Ivl=256ms

T:  Bus=01 Lev=00 Prnt=00 Port=00 Cnt=00 Dev#=  1 Spd=480  MxCh= 3
B:  Alloc=  0/800 us ( 0%), #Int=  0, #Iso=  0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=1d6b ProdID=0002 Rev= 3.16
S:  Manufacturer=Linux 3.16.0-49-generic ehci_hcd
S:  Product=EHCI Host Controller
S:  SerialNumber=0000:00:1a.0
C:* #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=  0mA
I:* If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub
E:  Ad=81(I) Atr=03(Int.) MxPS=   4 Ivl=256ms

T:  Bus=01 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=00 Cnt=01 Dev#=  2 Spd=480  MxCh= 6
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=8087 ProdID=8008 Rev= 0.04
C:* #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=  0mA
I:* If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub
E:  Ad=81(I) Atr=03(Int.) MxPS=   1 Ivl=256ms
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Bluetooth device is:

> Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0bda:b728 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.

And there is a know bug to this issue:
[[Realtek 0bda:b728] Bluetooth is useless after installed 14.04.2](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-lts-utopic/+bug/1433987)
You can click on the "**This bug affects # people. Does this bug affect you?**" string to state that you're affected as well. And subscribe to that bug to get updated.

Pilot6 provided a patch in comment #10 of that bug, which is:

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi
>   sudo apt-get update
>   sudo apt-get install rtl8723au-bt-dkms

You can try this out and reboot your system to see if it works.

Comment: after following the instructions and updating my system, bluetooth is finally working fine! thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

maybe this will be helpful:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2249996&highlight=bluetooth+issue

G;>=

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.